# Как удалить из индекса директорию, которая не существует на локальном компьютере?

Tags: git

В моем репозитории хранились бинарные файлы: картинки и др. Весили они очень много. На локальном компьютере я все это дело прибил. Не помню точно, по-моему с помощью `git rm`. Уже не помню, как я удалял из репы эти файлы, но я вижу, что git продолжает их хранить в своем индексе, так как при `git clone` репозиторий, который должен весить от силы один мегабайт, выкачивает целых 150 мегабайт! Поскольку мои познания в git дальше push и pull не продвинулись, задаю этот вопрос: как удалить из индекса директорию, которая не существует на локальном компьютере и в репозитории, но продолжает храниться в индексе?

Пробовал сделать следующее:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -f bin'
git gc; git prune; git repack -ad
git git push -f
```

Результат никакой. Несуществующая директория **bin** в репозитории продолжает отслеживаться и при клонировании тянет за собой 150 МГ.

Comment: К сожалению, этот способ не помог! На видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7oG6Sqx4cDs - видно, что директория **bin** так и отслеживается.

Comment: Почему не помог? Что вы сделали? Добавте эту информацию прямо в вопрос.

Comment: `rm -f bin` пытается удалить файл bin, а это директория. Попробуйте добавить `-r`.

Comment: Cannot create a new backup. 
A previous backup already exists in refs/original/ 
Force overwriting the backup with -f

Answer (score 0):

git clone
Удалить локально ненужную папку
git push --force

Comment: Директорий этих уже нет ни на локальном компьютере ни в репе.

Comment: Это не удалит ни одного файла из репозитория.